# Extremely slow perfomance with large dynamic tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am currently trying to implement Filter Widget External Search with Tablesorter into dynamic tables. However, with small tables (up to 10K rows) everything works fine. But with large datas (more than 10K rows) everything stucks and the page doesn't respond. Is there any way to somehow optimize the performance and make the filter widget work with more than 10K rows. I'm using TableSorter (FORK) 2.18.3, tablesorter (FORK) pager plugin updated 11/3/2014 (v2.18.2) and tableSorter (FORK) 2.16+ widgets - updated 11/7/2014 (v2.18.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [the issue that was opened](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/770), it isn't reasonable to try to display 10k rows all at once. No one with a mobile device will use your site because it will take too long to load.

Your best bet would be to serve a subset of your data using ajax. There is a [pager widget example](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-pager-ajax.html) showing how you can interact with your server. That being said, you would have to perform the sorting and filtering functions on your server and not client side.